# Super battery saver is turning off accessibility service

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

I am using accessibility service in my android application and it is working flawlessly until I turn on Super Battery Saver(which is provided in Xiaomi phones).Even after turning super battery saver off, my accessibility service isn't getting turned on automatically. I have to to turn it on myself. This happens even if I turn off battery optimizations for my app. Is there any way to make sure super battery saver doesn't stop accessibility service?

Comment: Have you read [Don't Kill my app! Xiaomi](https://dontkillmyapp.com/xiaomi)?

Comment: I followed all those steps but still my app got killed..